# How to completely disable the Task View feature in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, task-view

I want to disable Task View in Windows 10 completely. Is this possible?

Note: I know the button in the taskbar can be hidden by right-clicking it and unchecking “Show Task View button”. That’s not what I’m asking.

For example, when resizing and moving a window to the left half of the screen using `Win` + `←`, Task View is also activated. I don’t want this. I want the old, Windows 7 behavior, where the window is moved and resized and nothing else happens.

Comment: This question needs clarification. Are you asking specifically about the case in your "for example" sentence, or are you really asking how to complete disable Task View? These are not the same question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you only have 1 virtual desktop, taskview will not be active (default situation). So removing all virtual desktops except for the main one, and hiding the icon is all you need to do.

If you want to disable the overview screen, then go to start -> Settings -> Multitasking.

From the Snap menu, turn off `When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it`

Comment: It seems that my Ctrl + Win + Left/Right doesn't disable using this method. I would like to, if possible, turn off the feature that's bound to them.

Comment: Would be nice to have some further text that explains exactly what "Taskview" is. I've been a lifelong Windows user, and frankly I have no idea what taskview is. I just wanted to disable a feature that made all my Windows suddenly dissapear (I've never been a fan of virtual desktops anywhere). Edit: I assume I accidentally clicked (with my mouse?) on the "+ Desktop" thing which appears when pressing Windows key?

Comment: This answer is no longer correct (if it ever was). The question says "for example" but is asking how to disable the Task View. Disabling showing options to place beside a window and disabling the Task View are not the same question, so maybe the question is unanswerable as written. However, having only one virtual desktop does not disable the task view, so that part of this answer is wrong. I have only 1 virtual desktop, and the task view opens under many circumstances (sliding 3 fingers up on the touchpad, for instance).

Comment: @RandyCragun Congratulations. You replied to a question and answer from 2015. Back then, things were different yes. It is very much impossible to keep altering answers with the passage of time simply because the world around us is changing. The answer was valid at the time of writing though, which is all that matters, and the only reason the answer still exists is in case it is still partially correct which will help others to get closer to their solution. If you found out how it works nowadays, feel free to write an answer of your own though.

Comment: @LPChip I downvoted because it doesn't tell me how to disable the feature completely, which is what was asked in the question, and what I was searching for. You only covered how to not accidentally invoke it. If a politely worded comment had informed me that this disabled the feature entirely back in 2015, but no longer does so, then I might have reversed my vote. That said, one of SE's problems is old cruft that is no longer accurate, and I think downvoting such is perfectly fine. Our goal here is to make the most accurate Q&A site, not for individuals to get points.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will apply to everyones situation but I believe I understand what you're asking.

I tried all the solutions provided in this thread and none of them worked for me.

On my laptop I had to go into the touchpad settings (I've got a Dell) and turned off "Gestures" and the task view no longer appeared when I didn't want it to.

Comment: Yes, turning off 3 and 4 finger gestures will prevent switching desktops action.

Comment: I had the same issue as you that the previous solutions were already turned off. My Asus had a "swipe right from left edge" option marked that I need to remove! Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Keyword: Snap Assist.  Disable it!

> To disable Snap Assist in Windows 10, launch the Settings app from your Start Menu, or by searching for it with Cortana or Windows Search. From the Settings window, click System.
>
> In the System Settings window, find and click Multitasking in the column on the left. Under the “Snap” category on the right, find the option labeled When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it and set it to Off. This will disable Snap Assist in Windows 10.

Source: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-disable-snap-assist-windows-10/

This same issue was driving me crazy too.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to the original question, but this was the first search result on how to disable the activity history on the task view.

If that's what you need, you have to:

1. Open "Windows settings"
2. Go to "Activity history"
3. Uncheck "Store my activity history on this device"
4. Click "Clear" under "Clear activity history"